# Texto se muestra fuera de contenedor antes de mostrarlo con jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

tengo el siguiente código.

Lo que quiero es que al presionar el botón para desplegar información me muestre el texto que incluyo en la clase `.lorem`

Esto funciona en parte, porque el texto se está mostrando antes de desplegar el botón, lo que intenté en su momento fue incluir dicha clase al script que despliega la info, así:

```
$('.hint .lorem').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

Esto no me dió resultado.

Hay algo que esté haciendo mal?

```js
$('.hint').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #E0E5EC;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.lorem {
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #E0E5EC;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 16px rgb(163, 177, 198, 0.6), -9px -9px 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.card .hint {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: rgb(226, 45, 72);
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.card .hint .icon-info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.card .hint .icon-info:before,
.card .hint .icon-info:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.card .hint .icon-info:before {
  transform: translate(15px, 6px) rotate(0) scale(1, 0.2);
}

.card .hint .icon-info:after {
  transform: translate(15px, 12px) rotate(0) scale(1, 0.5);
}

.card .hint.show {
  width: calc(100% + 14px);
  height: calc(100% + 14px);
}

.card .hint.show .icon-info:before {
  transform: translate(15px, 10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.card .hint.show .icon-info:after {
  transform: translate(15px, 10px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="hint">
    <span class="icon-info"></span>
    <div class="lorem">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br><br>
      Maecenas ornare gravida imperdiet, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías agregar:

```
.lorem {
  display: none;
}

.card .hint.show .lorem {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
$('.hint').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #E0E5EC;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.lorem {
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #E0E5EC;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 16px rgb(163, 177, 198, 0.6), -9px -9px 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.card .hint {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: rgb(226, 45, 72);
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.card .hint .icon-info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.card .hint .icon-info:before,
.card .hint .icon-info:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.card .hint .icon-info:before {
  transform: translate(15px, 6px) rotate(0) scale(1, 0.2);
}

.card .hint .icon-info:after {
  transform: translate(15px, 12px) rotate(0) scale(1, 0.5);
}

.card .hint.show {
  width: calc(100% + 14px);
  height: calc(100% + 14px);
}

.card .hint.show .icon-info:before {
  transform: translate(15px, 10px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.card .hint.show .icon-info:after {
  transform: translate(15px, 10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.card .hint.show .lorem {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="card">
  <div class="hint">
    <span class="icon-info"></span>
    <div class="lorem">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br><br>
      Maecenas ornare gravida imperdiet, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta mi estimado, funciona correctamente